# Return type based on the type of a parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this: (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgUQMpwIwwLwwESJa7AbgCgoBPABwFN5k1Mc80jjjRJYmAmB3OrluWq0UPLH1EtiASzBQqAJwBmAQ2A0AgsCjTwcSlQCyKihBgBvYjGsi0ALhgBXMABMqS2VRckbtrg%20gFWQBzEgBfVioADwoQBVhZeWU1GgBJLR1wAB44GGj5VzMAayoyECUYDN0wfWpjUwA%20CysYISoHOB8YChUyABsQFRcHKr0DeogAbTgAXXDImLiEuUVVdRh07WqAdWkoAAsQRygABV6BoZy8qIKXYtLyyq2xupMIJstrNo6unv7B4ZOVzuTzeYgRYjRWLxGBKZzPMAwNSZMBXfJUQowEplCqjGrjN4NAAULW%208GIAEoHJsUbsDkdTucATkGiRIYsYXCwAikQi0TcMXcsQ9cQjakZCSSvgYOgAaFp-C6AvHiibTGaU6l4llsqFLWHwlG8lH8273HFPFGqyWkmXweXWRUAgD8IzFBNM6s1GzxdMOxzO-0ucCaAB8fXyQ81rNIKkSnUNMBgsM43B4wF4KdGbAoqFBHApEeZWgZZd0mUMHKmQRmXDAwoQYC0IdZc-nC9nHRWXA6bG1ew3waxkdUiUxUBTGwB6Kf7EwUMjEEfgMd0VBl7DyaDYLMzsAgWBzigLpcI1eiMuoLgAZl3U-3h-ni%20XYHPcC4d5gR4XMAARscYD2GAIH9PoXDAAByWBfyoIA))

```
const TEST1 = "TEST1";
type TEST1 = "TEST1";

const TEST2 = "TEST2";
type TEST2 = "TEST2";

interface ActionTypeMaps {
    TEST1: undefined;
    TEST2: string;
}

export interface IAction<T extends keyof ActionTypeMaps> {
  type: T;
  payload: ActionTypeMaps[T];
}

export interface IActionWithoutPayload<T extends keyof ActionTypeMaps> {
  type: T;
  payload: undefined;
}

export function action<T extends keyof ActionTypeMaps>(
  type: T
): IActionWithoutPayload<T>;

export function action<T extends keyof ActionTypeMaps>(
  type: T,
  payload: ActionTypeMaps[T]
): IAction<T>;

export function action<T extends keyof ActionTypeMaps>(
  type: T,
  payload?: ActionTypeMaps[T]
): IActionWithoutPayload<T> | IAction<T> {
  if (payload === undefined) {
    return { type, payload: undefined }; 
  }

  return {
    payload,
    type,
  };
}
```

This almost works you can do `action(TEST1)` and it's happy and you can do `action(TEST1, "test")` and then it will complain.

But you can also still do `action(TEST2)` which it shouldn't like. Here it should require you to pass a string as the second argument.

I need a way to say you can only call `action()` with one parameter when `ActionTypeMaps[T]` is `undefined` (or whatever other "not there" type you want to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by varying the amount of parameters it takes like this:

```
export function action<T extends keyof ActionTypeMaps>(
  ...[type, payload]: [ActionTypeMaps[T]] extends [never] ? [type: T] : [type: T, payload: ActionTypeMaps[T]]
): IActionWithoutPayload<T> | IAction<T> {
```

Just a small change to your map: I'd use `never` instead of `undefined`:

```
interface ActionTypeMaps {
    TEST1: never;
    TEST2: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3qnm)

Comment: Thank you! I first attempted this 4 years ago :D I just couldn't get my mind around this. I would never have thought of using an array spread to define arguments!